# Getting FB friends list using PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I want to know how to get FB friends list using php. How do I write code for this?

Comment: Stackoverflow is more of a Questions&Answers site than a forum. Please read the About and FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/about http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Have you read the Facebook Developer documentation? What have you tried? Do you have *anything at all*?

Comment: Facebook API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: It's been a while since I saw a real "send me teh codez" post :)

Answer (score 4):

You should find what you need by downloading the Facebook SDK and having a look inside example.php. The following shows one way of how this can be done via the graph API:

```
// Create our Application instance.
// Get your application id and secret from Facebook to fill these in
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => '12345...',
  'secret' => 'a1b2c3...',
  'cookie' => true,
));

//print_r($_REQUEST);

$fbUser = $facebook->getUser();

if ($fbUser) { 
  try { 
  $fbUserProfile = $facebook->api('/me'); // Get User
  $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends'); // Get Friends

  // Bonus: Get info from Coca-colas page. Requires no access token as public.
  // $cocacola = $facebook->api('/cocacola'); 

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) { 
  error_log($e); 
  $fbUser = null; 
  } 
} else {
   // There's no active session, let's generate one
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    // Extra permissions can be requested as follows:
    // $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'email, user_location')); 
    header("Location: ".$login_url);  
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($fbUserProfile);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($friends);
echo "</pre>";

echo("Hello " . $testuser->name);
echo("<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/{$fbUserProfile->id}/picture?type=large'>");
```

Comment: Countdown to "It says can't connect using appId '12345...'" in 10, 9, 8...

Comment: @Phil just seen this - classic! ha ha